# How to use STUnion with GroupBy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 to store Geometry data types.  I have a bunch of lines as individual features, that share common names ('NAME' field).  I would like to create a view that Groups By 'NAME' and combines the geometries.  I can only find STUnion function and I'm not sure how to use this to in a query to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately with SQL Server 2008 R2 your options are quite limited.

If you are able to enable CLR on your server, you can use something like [this](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/) to add extra capabilities, including aggregates.

Another option would be to create a procedure/function using `CURSOR`s to step through the dataset and do the Unioning.  This would likely to be quite slow.
Here's a quickly put together example that groups polygons for a specific table.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION AggregatePoly
    (@myGroupingCol int)
RETURNS Geometry
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @aggregate Geometry
    DECLARE @geom Geometry

    DECLARE cGEOM CURSOR STATIC LOCAL FOR
        SELECT SHAPE
        FROM myTable 
        WHERE myGroupingCol = @myGroupingCol

    OPEN cGEOM

    FETCH FROM cGeom INTO @geom
    SET @aggregate = @geom
    FETCH FROM cGeom INTO @geom
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
        SET @aggregate = @aggregate.STUnion(@geom)
        FETCH FROM cGeom INTO @geom
    END

    CLOSE cGeom
    DEALLOCATE cGeom

    RETURN @aggregate
END

SELECT g.*,
    dbo.AggregatePoly(g.myGroupingCol)
FROM (
    SELECT myGroupingCol, othercolumns -- Not SHAPE
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY myGroupingCol
    ) g
```

Probably the best option would be to use another piece of software to do the dissolve and save the results back to the database.  FME and Arc GIS spring to mind.

Another thing to beware of is that due to floating point issues you may end up with some slivers and holes in the resulting polygons.  You may need to do some small buffering of the base polygons to avoid it.  That also causes some issues, but that may be OK depending won what you want to do with the dissolved boundaries.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.  We use ArcGIS, but without an Arc server license, so I was hoping that SQL Server would be able to do some rudimentary visualisation for editing the features outside of Arc.  I'll likely just rely on having Access open alongside Arc to make sure the right lines are being edited.  

I haven't seen SQL used in this way before, as a programming language, a lot of new things to look up :-)  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I use the GEOMETRY::UnionAggregate function in SQL Server to do this for our Elem, Mid and High boundaries

In the dbo.SchoolBoundaries table below, the ELEM_NUM value is what I want to group on, and values of 0 are non-district boundaries (which I filter out):

```
SELECT elem_num
, GEOMETRY::UnionAggregate(shape) as shape
  FROM [dbo].[SchoolBoundaries]
  where ELEM_NUM > 0
  group by ELEM_NUM
```

Comment: Unfortunately UnionAggregate only became available in [SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929310(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: that's a bummer!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in SQL Server 2008 without the CURSOR overhead as STUnion applied to same geometry will result in same geometry, ie: *x.STUnion(x)=x*:

So MickyT's AggregatePoly function could be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION AggregatePoly
    (@myGroupingCol int)
RETURNS Geometry
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @gAggregate Geometry

    select @gAggregate = myGeomColumn.STUnion(isnull(@gAggregate, SHAPE))
    from myTable 
    WHERE myGroupingCol = @myGroupingCol

    RETURN @gAggregate
END
```

Comment: I'm stuck with @myGroupingCol.  It's a variable you don't declare, what's the intention with it?

Comment: My code block is intended to demonstrate the fact x.STUnion(x)=x and hence replace the necessity for CURSORs in MickyT's AggregatePoly function.  It was not intended to be complete stand-alone code.